# Superset table to Independent Sequential Ids for this dependents (1 to 1 relation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
Entities (EntityId PK)
  |-- Evaluations (EvaluationId PK, EntityId FK)

Chapters (ChapterId PK)
Sections (SectionId PK)
```

To create 1 to 1 relation between `Entities` and `Chapters` and `Entities` and `Sections` I would use:

```
Chapters (EntityId PK)
Sections (EntityId PK)
```

However I would like Chapters and Sections to have their own independent Sequential Id which I would use to get them.

`Entities` is just a superset table to define if an `Evaluation` is related to a `Chapter` or to a `Section`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I had a long answer here (where Entity table had a concatenated PK EntityType and EntityID), but I have deleted it. Why?

Taking a step back, I would think - for standard setups/etc, if you have an EntityID it should refer to one Entity, and one Entity only. In your suggestion, a given EntityID could refer to two different things (e.g., EntityID = 1 could refer to rows in both Chapters and Sections).

There is a lot of danger here for errors in SQL coding to produce very wrong results. I would suggest reconsidering whether this approach is a good one.

I suggest

- In your `Chapters` and `Sections` tables, have their own PK as your original example e.g., ChapterID and SectionID.

Then either

- In both Chapters and Sections tables have another field `EntityID` which is an FK to the `Entities` table, or
- In the `Entities` table, have two additional fields `ChapterID` and `SectionID` which is a reference to the other tables. Typically you'd only fill in one.

Therefore `EntityID` is unique.